# Route guard with auth.service

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-routing, angular6

I'm trying to create a route guard that keeps some lazy-loaded module safe, I have a auth service with BehaviorSubject that holds current user and JWT token

When I call the guard it first gets the default value of the current user and only on secend try it allow the user to get to the route.

auth.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map, skip, takeLast, last } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { User } from '../shared/user';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';


@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private loginUserToken: BehaviorSubject<string>;
  private currentUser: BehaviorSubject<User>;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    // service init
    this.loginUserToken = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);
    this.currentUser = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);
    this.loginUserToken.next(this.getTokenFromLocalStorege());
    if (this.loginUserToken.value != null) {
      this.getUserFromToken();
    }
  }
  /**
   * getLoginUser
   */
  public getLoginUserAsObservable() {
    return this.currentUser.asObservable();
  }
  public getLoginUserTokenAsObservable() {
    return this.loginUserToken.asObservable();
  }
  public async login(user: User): Promise<any> {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
    return new Promise<any>(async (resolve: any, reject: any) => {
      try {
        const result: any = await this.http.post(`${environment.server}/api/auth/login`, user).toPromise();
        if (result.massageCode === 1) {
          reject('bedUsername');
        } else if (result.massageCode === 2) {
          reject('bed password');
        } else {
          this.loginUserToken.next(result.token);
          this.getUserFromToken();
          this.saveTokenToLocalStorege(result.token);
          resolve();
        }
      } catch (error) {
        reject('error');
      }
    });
  }
  public getUserFromToken(): void {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'x-access-token': this.loginUserToken.value
    });
    this.http.get(`${environment.server}/api/auth/userFromToken`, { headers }).toPromise()
      .then((data: User) => {
        this.currentUser.next(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
  public isLogin(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.currentUser.asObservable()
      .subscribe((data) => {
        if (data) {
          resolve(true);
        } else {
          resolve(false);
        }
      }).unsubscribe();
    });
  }
  public saveTokenToLocalStorege(token: string): void {
    localStorage.setItem('chanToken', token);
  }
  public getTokenFromLocalStorege(): string {
    return localStorage.getItem('chanToken');
  }
  public removeTokenFromLocalStrege(): void {
    localStorage.removeItem('chanToken');
  }
}
```

auth.guaed.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, CanLoad, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { Route } from '@angular/compiler/src/core';
import { last, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanLoad {

  constructor(private authSerivce: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  canLoad(route: Route): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
    console.log('use gruad');
    return this.authSerivce.isLogin();
  }
}
```

Comment: You explicitly create a behaviour subject of undefined. If there isn't a sensible value prior to the response from the API, *don't give a default*. Also you should really be aware that you can turn observables directly into promises and vice versa, all the wrapping is unnecessary.

Comment: trying to remove the undefined result with an error , its required to have an inital value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because how a `BehaviourSubject` works. When you `Subscribe` to a `BehaviourSubject` it immediately returns the last value. That's why a `BehaviourSubject` needs a default value.

In your case as soon the `AuthGuard` gets activated it will call your method `isLogin` which subscribes to `currentUser` and it will return `undefined` (Depending on the sequence of javascript execution). Basically your `AuthGuard` will not wait for your function `getUserFromToken()` to finish.

You can easily solve this solution when you use `ReplaySubject` instead of `BehaviourSubject`.

`private currentUser: ReplaySubject<User> = new ReplaySubject(1)`

Initialize `ReplaySubject` with the value of 1 and it will cache your current user, but will not fire when there no user exist.

For now on your `Authguard` will wait for a valid `currentUser` value and will not fire when `currentUser` is undefined